# How to refresh Windows 10 taskbar thumbnail previews

Tags: windows, taskbar

The problem I have is in Windows 10, but it also happened in previous versions of Windows. The scenario is changing the display from an external display ('Second screen only') to the internal display (or vice versa). The result is taskbar thumbnail previews no longer display previews of each window's contents and instead display blank, gray images with an application icon.

Here is a picture of what I am describing:

[image]

The above image is of Chrome windows, but the problem occurs with the thumbnail previews of all open application windows.

I have tried the following solution:

1. Click on the Start Orb > right-click Computer > click Properties > click Advanced system settings
2. Under Performance click Settings > Check if Save taskbar thumbnail previews option is selected or not.
3. If not selected, select it.

That solution did not work.  The only way I can refresh the thumbnail previews is to go through and click on each individual one. That is a frustrating and time-consuming process when I have many windows open.

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer just the work arround I use to click them all efficiently.

1. Use **Windows-Key** + **tab** to display all thumbnail previews (this shows which thumbnail previews need refreshing.)
2. Move your mouse over the application at the bottom-right (why here? see below*)
3. Now repeat the steps 3a, 3b until all windows are maximized

   3a. **Windows-Key** + **tab**

   3b. **Click** bottom-right icon
4. **Windows-key** + **m** to minimize all these windows you just maximized which are now cluttering .
5. Now maximize any window you wish, all the thumbnail previews will be refreshed.

*So why the bottom-right?  Because as you maximize (i.e. refresh) each icon, it is moved to the top-left, and so when you press **Windows-Key** + **tab** each time a different unrefreshed preview will be sitting right under your mouse cursor waiting to be clicked.  So you won't need to move mouse and you can very quickly loop through all the applications in rapid fashion.  I can refresh 20 apps in 10 seconds this way.